Docker failed to pull image with specify policies
I am building up my CI flow with docker and Gitlab.
I've registered docker-runner in my server and made sure the image I built is in the server by "cmd: docker images" but I keep seeing the error message below.
According to the gitlab-ci.yml, when I push the code, the CI flow will be triggered and build my code base "test" in the container.
Thanks for your help!

This is my .gitlab-ci.yml
stages: 
    - build

build-code:
  stage: build
  script:
    - docker-compose up build

And docker-compose.yml:
version: '3'

services:
  build:
  volumes:
    - .:/test
  command: /bin/bash -c "\
    cd /test/cpp && \
    mkdir -p build && \
    cd build && \
    cmake .. && \
    make -j12"

update: seems no effect


The default behaviour of gitlab agents is "always pull" which you can see in your screenshot. This means even if you have a copy of the image locally, the agent will try to pull it again incase it has changed. To change this you need to edit the /etc/gitlab/config file

https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html

You might need to change your pull_policy to if-not-present in your config.toml.
Otherwise it will try to pull the image every time, even if it already exists.
[[runners]]
  (...)
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.docker]
    (...)
    pull_policy = "if-not-present"


Gitlab Doc

Hi, seems no effect, I've update a screenshot. Plz take a look, thanks!

Did you restart your runner? What is the output now? Please post the output text, and not images.
Is your runner running as a container?
You can try to change pull_policy to never.

Actually, I re-register the gitlab-runner but the config.toml become empty. Does it mean that I didn't register it successfully? But I still can see a green light in the Gitlab runner page.

Is there any method to reset the config file?

You need to give the basic information first. How are you running your runner?

I load the image in the server which has install the docker and gitlab-runner, then I registered the runner according to the instructions in gitlab web page. After I see the green light in the runner register page which means the runner works properly I try to push my code to the gitlab.
